# Ruby Mechanize Click Link without HREF

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to click on a link that doesn't have an HREF and has generated text. Here's my code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://stopandshop.shoplocal.com/")
links = page.search("div.rightSide > a")
result_page = Mechanize::Page::Link.new( links[1], agent, page ).click
puts result_page.title
pp result_page
```

I'm not getting any errors but the page is not changing (seen on pp result_page).

**How do I click the first link and get to the next page using Mechanize?**

Comment: When I load the url in the code you posted, I get redirected to an error page, so I can't really help, but if the href is generated client-side (javascript), you'll likely need to use a headless browser. Also, `links[1]` would get the second link, not the first.

Comment: If there's no href, there's really no point clicking it. Do you agree?

Comment: @pguardiario the <a></a> can call a JS method ;)

Comment: @GuillaumeAgis - Mechanize doesn't do js.